# Cakephp multiple relations based on other relations

Tags: cakephp, model, relation

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Schema:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b2LE.png

The only thing I dont have is the bottom line that links seat numbers together. I only want this link if the tiles seating chart has the same lan_id as user_seatings.lan_id

I need UserSeating to come up when I print out a find array on SeatingChartTiles.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I make for You tricky model linking. This is only one You need?

```
   public $hasMany = array(
        'SeatingChartTile' => array(
            'className' => 'SeatingChartTile',
            'foreignKey' =>'seat_number',
            'conditions' => array('SeatingChartTile.seat_number' => 'UserSeating.seat_number')
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hi. Which model would I put this in? Its incorrect if I put it in SeatingChart, and if i put it in UserSeating, UserSeating will not appear in the array I get from a $this->SeatingChartTile->findBySeatingChartId($blah);

Comment: For now I guess ill just have to run two different queries, but I would love to have this in my relation..

Comment: This if for model UserSeating, if you would like to ahve similar in model SeatingChartTile switch places SeatingChartTile and UserSeating in my sample

Comment: This is what I currently have as my model. http://i.imgur.com/vrTZh2A.png , note how I added another conditional in there, hopefully matching the lan_ids. Is this valid? I am now getting the error... 

` Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SeatingChartTile.id' in 'field list'
`

Comment: Could you show me all model Associations in SeatingChartTile?